# sublime text: hide view group without closing it

Tags: sublime-text-2, sublime-text-3, sublime-text

I open multiple groups in sublime and then want to temporarily hide some of them, in order to maximize the screen space of the others.

But I don't want to close the group, because I still want to use it later.

How can it be done?

Answer (score 1):

Use a plugin called [Sidebar Enhancements](https://github.com/titoBouzout/SideBarEnhancements), it provides SublimeText with more options and the posibility to minimize the opened groups in the sidebar.

Install it vía [Package Control](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Package%20Control).